# ion.rangeSlider lock the slider to predefined values

Tags: jquery, slider, rangeslider

Is there an option to lock the slider to predefined values? I mean

values: ["7.5", "15", "35", "65", "99", "125", "150", "199", "299", "399", "499"],

Now I want to only move "7.5" to 15,35.....499,

how it is possible? because when I start slider from "7.5" then it shows me 43, 79.I don't want these values , slider only move given values! Can you please!

```
    if($('#range_slider_a').length) {
            $("#range_slider_a").ionRangeSlider({
               type: "single",
                step: 10,
               postfix: " $",
               min: 7.5,
               max: 499,
               //from: 7.5,
               hasGrid: true,
            values: ["7.5", "15", "35", "65", "99", "125", "150", "199", "299", "399", "499"], 
              onChange: function(obj) {
                var current_price =     $('#range_slider_a').prop("value");
                $('#contact_limit').empty().append(''+current_price);
                $('#contact_price').empty().append(''+current_price);
                //alert(current_price);

             },
            });



        }
```

Comment: http://ionden.com/a/plugins/ion.rangeSlider/en.html

Answer (score 1):

maybe you are using old version of Ion.RangeSlider. Check the new version here: https://github.com/IonDen/ion.rangeSlider

Try this example to set up the slider correct way:

```js
var $range = $(".js-range-slider");

$range.ionRangeSlider({
    type: "single",
    postfix: " $",
    grid: true,
    values: ["7.5", "15", "35", "65", "99", "125", "150", "199", "299", "399", "499"]
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ion-rangeslider/2.3.0/css/ion.rangeSlider.min.css" integrity="sha256-nv5vSBJAzPy+07+FvRvhV2UPpH87H/UnWMrA6nbEg7U=" crossorigin="anonymous" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ion-rangeslider/2.3.0/js/ion.rangeSlider.min.js" integrity="sha256-eXdxIh/sjKTNi5WyC8cKHekwPywORiomyiMFyZsowWw=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="range-slider">
    <input type="text" class="js-range-slider" value="" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to change `from` to 0.
in your situation `from` is the index of `values` array, so if you want to start the slider from 7.5 you have to set 0 for `from` property.